# Why a serializable class must have the function that get the instance from class name?

Tags: serialization, mfc

Such as mfc, it should add

```
DECLARE_SERIAL(CGraph)
```

If I a have a class,

```
class A
{
    int a,b;
};
```

I can store the value of a and b to a file ,then read it.
So I couldn't understand why DECLARE_SERIAL(CGraph) used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DECLARE_SERIAL` and `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL` macros are only necessary for classes derived from `CObject` that you wish to serialize *polymorphically* using the framework provided by MFC.

If your class is not derived from `CObject` and/or you do not wish to use MFC's serialization polymorphically (i.e. via a pointer to `CObject`), then of course you can implement your own solution as you rightly say.

For example, `DECLARE_SERIAL(CMyClass)` expands to the following code that goes in your class declaration

```cpp
protected: 
    static CRuntimeClass* __stdcall _GetBaseClass(); 
public: 
    static CRuntimeClass classCMyClass; 
    static CRuntimeClass* __stdcall GetThisClass(); 
    virtual CRuntimeClass* GetRuntimeClass() const; 
    static CObject* __stdcall CreateObject();  
    friend CArchive& __stdcall operator>>(CArchive& ar, CMyClass* &pOb);
```

and `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(CMyClass, CObject, VERSIONABLE_SCHEMA | 1)` expands to the following code that goes in the cpp file

```cpp
CObject* __stdcall CMyClass::CreateObject() 
{ 
    return new CMyClass; 
} 

extern AFX_CLASSINIT _init_CMyClass; 

CRuntimeClass* __stdcall CMyClass::_GetBaseClass() 
{ 
    return (CObject::GetThisClass()); 
}

__declspec(selectany) CRuntimeClass CMyClass::classCMyClass = 
{ 
    "CMyClass", sizeof(class CMyClass), (0x80000000) | 1, 
    CMyClass::CreateObject, &CMyClass::_GetBaseClass, 0, &_init_CMyClass 
}; 

CRuntimeClass* __stdcall CMyClass::GetThisClass() 
{ 
    return ((CRuntimeClass*)(&CMyClass::classCMyClass)); 
} 

CRuntimeClass* CMyClass::GetRuntimeClass() const 
{ 
    return ((CRuntimeClass*)(&CMyClass::classCMyClass)); 
} 

AFX_CLASSINIT _init_CMyClass((CMyClass::GetThisClass())); 

CArchive& __stdcall operator>>(CArchive& ar, CMyClass* &pOb) 
{ 
    pOb = (CMyClass*) ar.ReadObject((CMyClass::GetThisClass())); 
    return ar;
}
```

As it [says in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ecfxkh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#_core_to_add_serialization_support) it is also possible to use serialization *without* using the above macros:

[image: MSDN]